# Radio button not display the correct fields when selected

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I've been trying to get the following code to display the corresponding table rows based on the radio button that is selected. Whats happening now is that once you select between the buttons the rows stop working and don't switch anymore. If I switch the radio buttons to check boxes the code runs just fine.

```js
var $options = $('[id^="option"]');

$options.on('change', function() {
  var $elementsToToggle = $('.' + this.value);
  if (this.checked) {
    $elementsToToggle.show();
  } else {
    $elementsToToggle.each(function() {
      var hide = true,
        elementToToggle = this;

      $options.each(function() {
        var optionClass = this.value,
          optionValue = this.checked;
        if (elementToToggle.classList.contains(optionClass) && optionValue)
          hide = false;
      });

      if (hide === true)
        $(elementToToggle).hide();
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.option1,
.option2,
.option3,
.option4 {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="option1btn" type="radio" value="option1" name="test">
<input id="option2btn" type="radio" value="option2" name="test">
<input id="option3btn" type="radio" value="option3" name="test">
<input id="option4btn" type="radio" value="option4" name="test">

<table id="optionTable">
  <tr class="option1">
    <td>option1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="option1">
    <td>option1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="option2 option4">
    <td>option2 option4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="option1 option4">
    <td>option1 option4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="option4">
    <td>option4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="option1 option3 option4">
    <td>option1 option3 option4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="option4">
    <td>option4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever the class of `<tr>` isn't part of radio button `id`, hiding it.

The issue with your code was that it wasn't entering the `else` at all, as `this.checked` is always true on change function. Hence, other `<tr>` weren't hidden after switching.

```js
var $options = $('[id^="option"]');
var $elements = $('[class^="option"]');

$options.on('change', function() {
  var $elementsToToggle = $('.' + this.value);
  if (this.checked) {
    $elementsToToggle.show();
    elementToToggle = this;
    var optionClass = this.value,
          optionValue = this.checked;
    $elements.each(function(idx,element) {
      var hide = true;
      if (element.classList.contains(optionClass) && optionValue)
          hide = false;
      if (hide === true)
        $(element).hide();
    });   
  } 
});
```

```css
.option1,
.option2,
.option3,
.option4 {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="option1btn" type="radio" value="option1" name="test">
<input id="option2btn" type="radio" value="option2" name="test">
<input id="option3btn" type="radio" value="option3" name="test">
<input id="option4btn" type="radio" value="option4" name="test">

<table id="optionTable">
  <tr class="option1">
    <td>option1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="option1">
    <td>option1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="option2 option4">
    <td>option2 option4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="option1 option4">
    <td>option1 option4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="option4">
    <td>option4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="option1 option3 option4">
    <td>option1 option3 option4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="option4">
    <td>option4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: is there a way to check if a radio button is already set to checked="checked" when the page loads? like `<input id="option1btn" type="radio" value="option1" name="test" checked="checked">`?

Comment: Yes. Use hasAttribute("checked") to check if the attribute exists on the element. Use getAttribute("checked") to get it value. if($("#option1btn")[0].hasAttribute("checked")){$("#option1btn")[0].getAttribute("checked")}

Answer (score 1):

```js
var $options = $('[id^="option"]');
ShowHideTr('option1')
$options.on('change', function() {
  var text = $(this).val();
  ShowHideTr(text);
});

function ShowHideTr(text)
{
   $('#optionTable tbody tr').each(function () {
  
   if($(this).children("td:eq(0)").html().indexOf(text) != -1)
      $(this).addClass('show');
   else
      $(this).removeClass('show');
   });
}
```

```css
.option1,
.option2,
.option3,
.option4 {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="option1btn" type="radio" value="option1" name="test" checked>
<input id="option2btn" type="radio" value="option2" name="test">
<input id="option3btn" type="radio" value="option3" name="test">
<input id="option4btn" type="radio" value="option4" name="test">

<table id="optionTable">
  <tr class="option1">
    <td>option1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="option1">
    <td>option1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="option2 option4">
    <td>option2 option4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="option1 option4">
    <td>option1 option4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="option4">
    <td>option4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="option1 option3 option4">
    <td>option1 option3 option4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="option4">
    <td>option4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I Would try out a different event than 'change' for the radio buttons, check out here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp